# Code completion for functions in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

When I start typing function name (declared by myself) in PhpStorm there is no function name in dropdown list. Furthermore, using <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> and so on also has no effect.

How to fix this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you save live template properly?

Comment: I admit this should be obvious to answer but I'm also finding it difficult to find documentation re this question. In my PhpStorm it simply works.

Comment: Works just fine for me (see https://postimg.cc/wtqVkXzn) has to be specific to your setup or file. To start with: try `File | Invalidate Caches` and restart IDE. If still the same -- try disabling all custom (not bundled by default) plugins and restart IDE. If still nothing -- try that in a differently named file in a brand new project. Still nothing -- you need to provide some info about your setup/IDE.

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help. Run PHPstorm on next day - everything works OK. So it was temporary bug.
I'm just studying PHP, all tools are new, so it's not always clear, where it's bug or where need to go to settings :) Thanks again.